# Best way for conditional join - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, table A always has data, and table B can be empty. When I know that table B is empty, I would like to set the @Filter parameter to 0 and view all the records in table A (then ignoring table B). When I know that table B is not empty I would like to set the @Filter parameter to 1 to show only the rows in common between the two tables (using columns X and Y).

I never found a definitive solution and I tried different ways but none of these I like:

- **exec @sqlString**: potential sql injection / not very readable code (IMHO)
- **UNION**: My query is too large to duplicate
- **OR in WHERE condition**: Too slow in some cases

  ```
   DECLARE @Filter BIT = 0

   SELECT A.*
   FROM   A, B
   WHERE  @Filter = 0 OR (B.X = A.X AND B.Y = A.Y)
  ```

Does anyone know an alternative way?

Comment: LEFT JOIN something?

Comment: You have what is known as a catch-all query. These are very common in searches. They can be challenging for sure. Gail Shaw has a great article in this topic here. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ And here is another from Erland Sommarskog http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Answer (score 4):

Start with a left-join to B so you ALWAYS get A-B relationship established.

Then, in your where clause, test your filter.
If 0, get them all

OR

If 1 AND Ensure the B.X field IS NOT NULL (thus exists) and you return only those records within both tables.

```
SELECT 
      A.* 
   FROM 
      A LEFT JOIN B 
           ON A.X = B.X AND A.Y = B.Y
   where
           @Filter = 0
      OR ( @Filter = 1 AND NOT ISNULL( B.X ))
```

Comment: unfortunately this slows down my query

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `IF` statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 X FROM B) -- make sure something is there
  BEGIN
    -- if there is, do the join
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON B.X = A.X AND B.Y = A.Y
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- nothing in B, select everything from A
    SELECT *
    FROM A
  END
```

Comment: This can lead to some pretty difficult performance problems. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: I would not duplicate my SELECT, sorry

Comment: @SeanLange True, but considering we have very little information on the nature of these tables and the OP has already discounted using UNION, WHERE and dynamic SQL.  This is just another alternative (though not my preferred one).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM
   A  
WHERE 
   EXISTS(SELECT 1 from B WHERE A.X = B.X AND A.Y = B.Y)
   OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B)
```

it will display all records from table A if table B is empty and only common records from table A when table B is not empty

Full Code:

```
declare  @A table
(
    x int,
    y int 
)
declare  @B table
(
    x int,
    y int 
)

insert into @A
values(1,1),
(1,2)

--Uncomment code below to insert data in table B
--insert into @B
--values(1,1) --,
--(1,2)

SELECT A.* 
FROM
   @A A 
WHERE 
   EXISTS(SELECT 1 from @B B WHERE A.X = B.X AND A.Y = B.Y)
   OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @B)
```